# How to get the data inside the observer?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

when getting the data from the observer in the console I have this:

[image]

however, I only need to get this data from each of the list:

[image]

to get the observer I just need to do:

```
this.item.specialties
```

How can I get an array with only the id? Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: Thanks, looking for an answer I found an easy way to access the data individually I just use `this.item.specialties[1].id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the array into a new array.

Assuming `this.item.specialties` is an array of objects, each containing an `id` property, you would do this:

```js
const ids = this.item.specialties.map(item => item.id)
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this works perfectly! Thanks